# Find the equation for the angle in which the particle abandons the hemicircle. No friction.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

I think I missed something in this mechanics problem.

We're given a polish and homogeneous hemicircle which has mass $M$ and a particle of mass $m$ laying on the top of it.[image]

There is also no friction between the hemicircle and the ground. Find the equation for the angle $\theta$ in which the particle abandons the hemicircle surface.

I can't find my mistake.

As we have no external horizontal forces acting on the system particle + hemicircle we must have conservation of the horizontal position of the center of mass.

I made this horrible drawing to try to understand the movement:

[image]

we would have $x = \frac{mR \sin(\theta)}{M+m}$, making $M = k \cdot m \iff k = \frac M m$, we would have:

$$x = \frac{R \sin(\theta)}{1+k} \implies \dot x = \frac{R \dot \theta \cos(\theta)}{1+k}$$

from this, I found that the velocity of the particle with respect to the ground was:

$$R \dot \theta (\cos (\theta)(\frac k{k+1})u_x - \sin (\theta) u_y) = \vec v_P $$

And conservation of energy

$$mgR = mgR\cos(\theta) + \frac{mv_P^2+ M \dot x^2}2$$

gave me:

$$2\frac gR(1-\cos(\theta))(1+k) = \dot \theta^2 [\sin^2(\theta) +k]$$

Finally, I used the abandonment equation: $\frac gR \cos(\theta) = \dot \theta^2$

Which led me to:

$$3 \cos(\theta) - \frac{\cos^3(\theta)}{1+k} = 2$$

but I feel something is wrong because $k=0$ should give me $\cos(\theta) = \frac23$ any insights on my mistakes?

EDIT: I think on the line of the energy conservation the term $\sin^2(\theta)$ is the one causing trouble. I'm very confident about the expression for the velocity of the particle.

Comment: Your interpretation for $k=0$ is wrong. You get $\cos\theta=2/3$ only if $M$ does not move. The equivalent for that is $M$ is much much larger than $m$, or $k=\infty$. $k=0$ is equivalent of $M=0$. So it takes no effort to move $M$ out of the way. $m$ will fall straight down, and will leave the sphere at $\cos\theta=1$, or equivalent, as soon as the system starts to move.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Assuming that the movement occurs into a maximum declivity plane, and calling $A$ the semi-sphere center and $B$ the $m$ mass position, we have

$$
B = A + R(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
$$

then $\dot B = \dot A + R(\cos\theta,-\sin\theta)\dot\theta$ so the lagrangian can be established as

$$
L = \frac 12 m \|\dot B\|^2+\frac 12 M\|\dot A\|^2-m g R\cos\theta
$$

with $A = (a,0)$ and the movement equations (while in contact) are

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \ddot a& =& \frac{m \sin (\theta) \left(R \dot\theta^2-g \cos (\theta)\right)}{M+m-m \cos ^2(\theta)} \\
 \ddot\theta&=&\frac{\sin (\theta) \left(m R \dot\theta^2 \cos (\theta )-g (m+M)\right)}{m R \cos ^2(\theta)-R (m+M)} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: well, $A = a(1,0)$ so we would have $a$ and $\theta$ as coordinates, but be carefull because $M\dot A + m\dot B$ is not zero, only its horizontal component is. But nice, I didn't think about the Lagrange equation in this one

Comment: I think $\lambda$ is just a real scalar and that the constraint is just the horizontal component of the vector $M \dot A + m \dot B$